# Capturing Audio Data from Windows XP

Tags: c++, driver

I have an requirement to send audio stream from a Remote machine(Windows XP) to Local machine...

Description:

When a user connect to a remote machine (via mstsc) by selecting the option Play in Remote Computer,then according our requirement whatever a user play at remote machine that should be played at Local machine...

In window Vista and 7 we have WASAPIs by using that we can capture the audio whatever playing at remote machine and send it to Local machine...

Is there any method for Windows XP to do that .First I need to capture the audio stream at remote machine(Windows XP) and send it back to local machine as long as the audio is playing at remote machine?